# Error using Directive ngModel in angular 2

Tags: angular

Just trying to learn Angular and facing an error.

```
@Component({
template:`
<input [(ngModel)]="email" (keyup.enter)="onAnotherBinding()"/>
`
})

export class CoursesComponent implements OnInit {
email = "abc@email.com"

  onAnotherBinding(){
    console.log("the data entered by the user is --> " + this.email);
  }
}
```

I get the following error on running this :

```
compiler.js:15826 Uncaught Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!
    at _AstToIrVisitor.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js._AstToIrVisitor.visitPropertyWrite (compiler.js:15826)
    at PropertyWrite.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.PropertyWrite.visit (compiler.js:3311)
    at convertActionBinding (compiler.js:15513)
    at compiler.js:17074
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ViewBuilder.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.ViewBuilder._createElementHandleEventFn (compiler.js:17070)
    at nodes.(:4200/anonymous function) (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:22812:23)
    at compiler.js:17032
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at ViewBuilder.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.ViewBuilder._createNodeExpressions (compiler.js:17031) push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js._AstToIrVisitor.visitPropertyWrite @ compiler.js:15826 push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.PropertyWrite.visit @ compiler.js:3311 convertActionBinding @ compiler.js:15513 (anonymous) @ compiler.js:17074 push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.ViewBuilder._createElementHandleEventFn @ compiler.js:17070 nodes.(anonymous function) @ compiler.js:16668 (anonymous) @ compiler.js:17032 push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.ViewBuilder._createNodeExpressions @ compiler.js:17031 push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.ViewBuilder.build @ compiler.js:16503 push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.ViewCompiler.compileComponent @ compiler.js:16425 push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate @ compiler.js:23988 (anonymous) @ compiler.js:23930 push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents @ compiler.js:23930 (anonymous) @ compiler.js:23840 then @ compiler.js:1007 push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @ compiler.js:23839 push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ compiler.js:23799 push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js.CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync @ platform-browser-dynamic.js:143 push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:4352 ./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76 0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76 checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:43 webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:30 (anonymous) @ main.js:1
```

Comment: This error is not related to ngModel directive. Might be some other issue

Comment: Just a thought, if you are asking a question... make sure that the question has all included that causes the issue. Just if you were to test the code you presented, it works just fine ;) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l4tlk2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts Maybe try and reproduce the issue in stackblitz?